# Windows 8.1 dual boot with Ubuntu doesnt find Windows 8.1 partion

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I recently tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 on my PC. When i get to step of the installation process where i should be able to choose the installation type, the dual boot option is not there and it says that there're no operative systems installed when i really have Windows 8.1 x64.

Can anyone please help me fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it fails to detect the other OS
You could go for manual partition by clicking on the "**something else**"option available
From there you can see a list of drives.Where you need to select a freespace or the drive you may want to install your ubuntu.

In the avalibale freespace you could add a swap drive by add button where you can select it as "swap".

Now using the add button by clicking on the freespace available and give the option "ext4" in the use it as option

Set the mount point to /

Now you could select the ext4 drive which you added now and click on the Install option available.